# apt upgrade breaks a manually installed nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, upgrade, vulkan

I am currently developing with vulkan on ubuntu and I need a vulkan ready driver.

The drivers at https://launchpad.net/~canonical-x/+archive/ubuntu/vulkan are not uptdated very often and are very buggy for me. The biggest problem is that they break hibernate for me.

I have no problems with the manual installed nvidia driver from https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver but it seems that `apt upgrade` randomly breaks the driver and I am not sure why.

I don't want to reinstall the driver every week, is there a proper way to install the nvidia driver manually so that they do not break with `apt upgrade`?

Comment: "randomly breaks" is not much useful. Do you remember to reinstall them after every kernel update? If not, that might be the issue. Try to pay attention to what gets updated when it "breaks" them.

Answer (score 1):

The full text for `pinning` a package at a specific level can be found here: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction%20to%20Holding%20Packages)

To find out the Nvidia packages installed (on my system) I did this:

```
rick@dell:/boot/grub$ sudo apt list nv* | grep install

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

nvidia-367/xenial,now 367.44-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-opencl-icd-367/xenial,now 367.44-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-prime/xenial,xenial,now 0.8.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/xenial,now 370.28-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

To freeze the package at current level (`Pin it`) type the following:

```
root@dell:/boot/grub$ sudo -i
root@dell:~# echo nvidia-367 hold | dpkg --set-selections
root@dell:~# echo nvidia-opencl-icd-367 hold | dpkg --set-selections
root@dell:~# echo nvidia-prime hold | dpkg --set-selections
root@dell:~# echo nvidia-settings hold | dpkg --set-selections
root@dell:~# exit
```

Unfreezing or reversing the holds is the same but instead of `hold` use `unhold`.