# Installing a Nvidia driver manually with apt update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

As many will know, Nvidia drivers are a mess in Ubuntu.
I have an Nvidia GeForce 9600GT (super old card, I know), and the default system offered driver for it (version 340.108) natively just doesn't support kernel versions newer than 5.8 .

It apparently was just a small error since I found a nice patch that allowed me to manually install the driver on the latest kernel. problem is - now every time there's a kernel upgrade I have to again drop to root shell and reinstall the driver to build it on the latest kernel installed.

I saw someone referring to the issue in here:
[apt upgrade breaks a manually installed nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834974/apt-upgrade-breaks-a-manually-installed-nvidia-driver).

But I would like to ask something specific - Is there a neat option to add a script that checks before booting whether the latest kernel has any Nvidia driver install and if not then install it?

The patch that I used is found in here: https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2020/inttf-nvidia-patcher/

The system I'm using:

```
Linux 5.13.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

the graphics card:

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] (rev a1)
```

Comment: @ubfan1, I think the last part of the post simply points to a script that the OP wants to run. However, the question is, how to automatically run this script (to re-build the NVIDIA driver), whenever a new kernel is installed?

Comment: How does it work with the community open-source driver `nouveau`? Probably just as fine so use it instead of an "hacked" old proprietary driver. You're using a legacy and unsupported (by Nvidia) hardware. It's trivial to keep the support with newer drivers but Nvidia deliberately doesn't do that.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Now the problem with nouveau is that there are random freezes which I can do nothing about. But - with the Nvidia driver everything runs super smooth.